# 他の人が公開しているコードを試して、そのエラーの原因がわからない時

Tags: サポート

他の人が公開しているコードを試して、そのエラーの原因がわからない時にスタック・オーバーフローで質問をするのはアリでしょうか?

Comment: 特に問題ないと思いますが、不明点を整理して投稿していただくと良いかと。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OKです。ヘルプページの[「良い質問をするには？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)も参考になります。

ただし、ソースコードのライセンスが問題になるような転載の仕方をしないようにお気を付けください。引用の範囲に収めるのが安全です。

Answer (score 1):

- 広く知られたライブラリでもない限り、基本的にはプログラムを書いた本人が一番内容について把握しているはずです。まずは作者に直接コンタクトを取ることも(取りうる行動の候補として)検討してみてください。
  もし問題が元のプログラムにある場合、フィードバックを送ってあげることはお互いの助けになるはずです。
- 公開されている時点で再利用されることについては元の作者も折り込み済みだと思いますが、念のため再配布等に関する断り書きが無いかは確認してください。
  「自由に使ってもらって構わないけど、改変したものを再配布はご遠慮ください」などとしている場合もあります。
- 情報源がwebページでも書籍でも、できるだけ引用元を明記してください。著作権等の問題もそうですし、問題が転記(コピペ)ミスの場合やプログラムを動かすための前提条件などを確認する際の手助けとなります。
- 質問する以上は自分で書いた場合と同じように最低限プログラムの内容を他人に説明できる様にしておく必要があります。「中のロジックで何をしてるか分からないけど何かエラーが出ます」だけでは、質問を見る側も困ってしまいます。